# Bundling Elixir Project into single file

Tags: elixir

I have an elixir project with several files in it. I was wondering if there is a tool using which I can bundle (merge) all the elixir files into one single file, for the purpose of deployment.

TIA :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Exrm](https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm). Then you can build a release with:

```
mix release
```